# Что такое .inc файлы

Tags: c++, include

Зачем нужны .inc файлы, и что в них записывают?

Comment: Обычно такое расширение у заголовочных файлов, которые включают в середину файла, среди прочего когда, либо для многократного включения, либо и то, и другое. Но так делать не стоит.

Comment: Да что угодно в них может быть. Расширение файла не описывает его содержимого. Видел применение, как описано выше.